# %d format a number is required not str

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table named tablename with idno as primary kry. I want the row to be deleted if the user specifies the idno in the table.
Here are my codes:

```
data3=raw_input("Enter the idno to del :",)
mydata=cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tablename where idno=%d", data3)
db.commit()
```

I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\trertr.py",
>   line 50, in 
>       mydata=cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tablename where idno=%d", data3)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line
>   187, in execute
>       query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args]) TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: inserted those user input values into a table. gave delete command like delete from table where sex = F. it works but I couldnt figure out how to delete the entire row using primary key

Comment: I want to know how to get a row using primary key, delete the row if idno is 102, if idno is 101 then update the name as abc

Comment: I havent posted the codes of raw input, delete commands and all cos this is just a part of my program. The rest of my code works well

Comment: @AzatIbrakov check out my codes

Comment: what for `while tries > 3:`?

Comment: your `choice` will be `str` and you are comparing it with `int` objects

Comment: Im not comparing anything here. That part works fine. age is in int and if i give some str, the for loop will run again and this can happen a max of 2 times. Tries refers to the number of times the inner for loop can run. I dont want it to throw an error first time

Comment: at first you are doing `choice=input("Enter a choice:")`, `choice` has type `str`, then comparing with 1: `if choice==1:`

Comment: like if i give choice==1, i want the while n for loop inside it to work. if i give 2, delete command and for 3 update command should work. I'm not facing any issues there. Pls leave it

Comment: This is a repetitive loop which works infinite times until user chooses 8 to exit. cursor.execute commands in update and delete should be changed so that those operations can be performed using primary key, instead of pre defining it

Answer (score 0):

```
data3=int(raw_input("Enter the idno to del :",))

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tablename where idno=%s", [data3])
```

After a lot of tries, I have got the answer which worked for me