# Python: Can't insert list values into a mysql column

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have an int list `list = [1, 2, 3]`

And a mysql table with an empty second column:

```
key value
a 
b
c
```

I want to populate the `value` column with values from my list so as to make the table look like this:

```
key value
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

But I am always getting a **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

My python code is:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root")
cursor = conn.cursor()
list = [1, 2, 3]
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO my_table (value) VALUES %d", list)
```

How am I to solve the issue and get the empty column populated?
Thanks!

P.S.: this is just a sample. In reality, the list and the table are much bigger.

Answer (score 3):

You need a list of lists or tuples.

```
my_list = [[1], [2], [3]]
```

(Also, don't overwrite the built-in `list()` type with your own variable.)

Comment: Thanks! But now I get `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: %d format: a number is required, not str`. Changed %d to %s which triggered `1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;`. Tried the solution from [this stackoverflow ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585105/d-format-a-number-is-required-not-str), but no like either. How am I to solve this?

Comment: The placeholder should always be `%s`.

Comment: I have changed the last line to `cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO my_table (value) VALUES %s", list)`, but got another error: `1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;`. Could you please give me a hint on how to fix that?